# With Python and Flask. I am trying to have my flash message disappear after a few seconds using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

Below is my flash messages using Jinja2. {{ message }} is where I want to have disappear after a few seconds.

```
<div class='messages' id='messages'>
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <li class='messages'> {{ message }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
</div>
```

This is my javascript. I am new to using javascript so I might not be properly using it.

```
message = document.getElementsByClassName('li.messages')

setTimeout(function(){
    $('li.messages').fadeOut();}, 5000);
```

Comment: What is it doing now?  Is this javascript present in your page source? Do you see any javascript errors in the browser console?

Comment: In my javascript console it saying my main.js (which is the name of my file) is not defined.

Comment: That would be a problem.

Comment: i defined it, now it just not working.

Comment: "It's not working" tells us us very little.  What is it doing?  Anything?  Do you get an error?  Are the `<li>` elements present on the page?

Comment: Have you tried making a simple test page in pure html/javascript, without jinja, to see if the code works?